# How to display the logged in username in twig file in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-8

I want to display the username of the current logged-in user in twig file of my custom theme in Drupal 8. Please advise!

Answer (score 2):

`{{ user.displayname }} woked for me.`

Reference from 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Session!AccountInterface.php/function/AccountInterface::getDisplayName/8.3.x